# Can alumnus be used for both men and women?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you call someone who chooses to quit his/her study in college as alumnus?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49361/can-you-call-someone-who-chooses-to-quit-his-her-study-in-college-as-alumnus)

Is it correct or acceptable to use *alumnus* for both genders?

Comment: This is answered within previous question "[Can you call someone who chooses to quit his/her study in college as alumnus?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49361)"

Comment: I was going to close as duplicate, but I can't actually find an authoritative answer at the other question. The answers there mention that *alumnus/alumni* are male and *alumna/alumnae* are female, but there's nothing reliable about using *alumnus* for females (the way "actor" and other words are now gender-neutral). It's not clear if the answers on that question should be interpreted as saying "no, it is not acceptable to use *alumnus* for both genders".

Comment: Maybe not a duplicate, but I downvoted as no research is shown, and voted to close as general reference.

Comment: @Hugo: Even with enough research, I cannot find the answer in general references: they variously say that *alumnus* is "male", or "especially male", or don't. :-(

Answer (score 5):

I do not think it is correct to use in *both*. However, it is correct and preferable to use in a gender-neutral, general application. "A person who is an *alumnus* of ..." would be fine, without necessarily implying that it includes only the men.

Comment: It will be nice if that settles the controversy for once and forever.

Comment: As stated alumnus (plural alumni) is male and alumna (alumnae) is female, however it IS correct to use alumni for a mixture or gender-neutral plural.